# PHP Trying to redirect url by writing JavaScript code

Tags: php, javascript

When I have

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- window.location = "newthread.html" //--> </script>
```

the redirect works fine, i would like it to be control by php code, but when I try

```
<?php print('<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- window.location = "newthread.html" //--> </script>'); ?>
```

It does not work.

Comment: Three years, 290 questions **and you still can't be bothered to format your code**?

Comment: Why involve JavaScript for this? Why even involve HTML? Just use an HTTP redirect.

Comment: You must be omitting something. Both snippets are identical.

Comment: Why is it so much to ask for you to make some attempt at spelling? You seem to spell some words differently each time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  $pagename="foo.php?bar=123";
  echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \n <!-- \n top.location.href='$pagename'; \n //--> \n </script>");
  exit();
```

This will work **after** something has been output, in contrast to `header`

Why the down votes?

Answer (score 2):

Use a php [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) directive. This directive has to happen at the very top of your script, before anything is outputted to the page.

```
<?php
header("Location: newthread.html");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a redirect by the server you need to return a redirect header (not a client-side-script for redirection) before anything else is returned to the user

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Code:

```
<? header('Location: newthread.html'); ?>
```